# XSLT to wrap XML data in html tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML node containing data I want to turn into an unordered list. Like so:

```
<list><![CDATA[*Lorem ipsumdolor sit  *consectetur adipiscing elit, * sed do eiusmod * tempor incididunt ut]]></list>
```

I'm wanting to separate the list elements on the asterisks.

So the output will be:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsumdolor sit</li>
    <li>consectetur adipiscing elit,</li>
    <li>sed do eiusmod</li>
    <li>tempor incididunt ut</li>
</ul>
```

I first tried using a recursive string replace template applied to the data, but I was having trouble wrapping the end up in an`</li>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <ul>
        <xsl:call-template name="li">
            <xsl:with-param name="listdata" select="string(.)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="li">
    <xsl:param name="listdata"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lidata">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($listdata, '*')">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($listdata, '*'))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($listdata)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lidataremaindata" select="normalize-space(substring-after($listdata, '*'))"/>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($lidata) != ''">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="$lidata"/>
    </li>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($lidataremaindata) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="li">
            <xsl:with-param name="listdata" select="$lidataremaindata"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice solution.